# Message.CreateMessage in IErrorHandler creates different message without wrapper element / namespace

Tags: wcf, serialization, soap, datacontract, ierrorhandler

I've got a strange issue as  result of trying to remove aspect oriented code from all of our web services.

There's a IParameterInspector that does validation and throws a FaultException that is caught in an IErrorHandler that is returning a response.

ResponseBase looks like this:

```
 [DataContract(Namespace = Namespaces.Data)]
public class ResponseBase
{
    public ResponseBase()
    {
        this.Build = BuildHelper.GetBuild();
    }

    [DataMember(Name = CommonParameterNames.RequestId, Order = 0)]
    public string RequestId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = CommonParameterNames.Status, Order = 1)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = CommonParameterNames.Errors, Order = 2, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Error[] Errors { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = CommonParameterNames.Build, Order = 3, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Build Build { get; set; }
}
```

This is the base class for all responses created by web service methods.

When it is returned from a wervice method without an error or validation error occurred, the Message contains a wrapper element in the body having a namespace, called "response", right after the opening tag of the method name itself:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body>
  <BulkUploadImageBase64Response xmlns="http://www.mydomain.com/webapi/">
     <response xmlns:a="http://www.mydomain.com/webapi/data/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <a:request_id>
```

However, if I try to handle the fault in the IErrorHandler, using Message.CreateMessage() method, passing the ResponseBase object from the FaultException, the result looks different:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body>
  <BulkUploadImageResponse xmlns="http://www.mydomain.com/webapi/data/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <request_id>e505d0d3-fc5d-474f-8ec7-5c7521c8a869</request_id>
     <status>DataValidationError</status>
```

The Message returned from the error handler seems to be serialized in a different way. The "response" wrapper element is missing for some reason.

This is the Error Handler implementation (excerpt):

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        if (error is FaultException<ResponseBase>)
        {
            var fe = error as FaultException<ResponseBase>;
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, null, fe.Detail);
        }
```

I've already tried different thing: using a BodyReader together with a DataContractSerializer, adding a MessageContract attribute to the ResponseBase class, and so on, but I can't make it look like the response message generated by the framework implicitly.

Any help is appreciated very much, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just ran into the same issue and managed to get the response from `ProvideFault` to match the usual response.

Here's the gist of it:

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
{
    if (error is FaultException<ResponseBase>)
    {
        var fe = error as FaultException<ResponseBase>;
        var action = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action;
        var operation = OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Operations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Action == action);

        // Instantiate a serializer that will wrap the response like the service would, based on the operation name
        var serializer = new FaultSerializer(operation.Name);

        // Create the message
        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, operation.ReplyAction, fe.Detail, serializer);
    }
}
```

Then the serializer would look something like this:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    internal class FaultSerializer: XmlObjectSerializer
    {
        private readonly string _actionName;

        public FaultSerializer(string actionName)
        {
            _actionName = actionName;
        }

        public override bool IsStartObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
        {
            // Not used
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, bool verifyObjectName)
        {
            // Not used
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteEndObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

        public override void WriteObjectContent(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, object graph)
        {
            // Instead of naming the main object element with the object type,
            // append Result to the action name
            var xmlDictionary = new XmlDictionary();
            var settings = new DataContractSerializerSettings {
                RootName = xmlDictionary.Add($"{_actionName}Result")
            };

            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(graph.GetType(), settings);
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, graph);
        }

        public override void WriteStartObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, object graph)
        {
            // Wrap the entire object in a Response element
            writer.WriteStartElement($"{_actionName}Response", "http://tempuri.org/");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!